# Installed TOR, looking to install/run TOR browser

Tags: browser, tor

I installed the TOR client, that's all set. Says "successfully opened a circuit".

Now, I would like to know how to set up a browser with it. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and didn't install TOR through the official repos.

Answer (score 1):

the installation gonna be like this

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/tor-browser
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install tor-browser
```

open the tor browser look for app named :  tor-browser

Comment: hahaha ty so much! why was it so hard to find those few lines on web?? SOLVED

Comment: not sure how to tagged as solved   :(

Comment: it's not a problem 'your problem has been solved '